# What did Bronstein et al 2021 mean by "conductance"?

Tags: geometric-deep-learning

On page 24 of *[Geometric Deep Learning: Grids, Groups, Graphs, Geodesics, and Gauges](https://arxiv.org/abs/2104.13478)* they make the following statement:

> An essential aspect of Fourier transforms is that they reveal *global* properties of the signal and the domain, such as smoothness and conductance.

What do they mean by "conductance" here?

Comment: I haven't time to read the paper, but Conductance in graph theory [controls how fast a random walk on G converges to its stationary distribution.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conductance_(graph)), is this paragraph in any related to such? I don't have the context but it's my best guess. In terms of signals, the only "conductance" I could find would relate to electrical conductance, but I don't see how that would be relevant here unless the paper went on quite a tangent

Comment: @Recessive Thank you! That is a plausible interpretation.